# Find the difference between the maximum and the minimum value of the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the difference between the maximum and the minimum value of the function $y = \sqrt{100-x^2}$ on the segment $[-4\sqrt2 ; 5\sqrt3]$.

Maximum value is $10$, minimum value is $5$. But what if $y$ is more complex ? Is there a  different way to solve this problem, maybe using differentiation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question, the maximum value is clearly $10$ and the minimal value occur when the magnitude of $x$ is the largest.

Calculus approach:

$$y' = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{100-x^2}}$$

The stationary point is $0$ of which the correponding objective value is $10$.

After which, we can compare the objective value at the stationary point and the boundary point and conclude that the minimal value is $5$ and compute the difference.

You can also check that square root is an increasing function, and focus on finding the extrema of $100-x^2$ over the domain directly.

- For higher dimensions and more complicated domain/constraints, do check out concept such [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), convexity, coercive function. For non-smooth function, you might like to consider subgradient, branch and bound/ branch and price/ branch and cut. Optimization is a very broad topic and there is no silver bullet.

Comment: The 2 won't be there in differentiation.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: You should also include the double (or more depending on situation) derivative test for maxima or minima with 0, it is obvious here but still, as a part of theory.